# How can I avoid errors in three.js?

Tags: three.js

i have this simple three.js sample which i test via visual studio code with live preview server build in: i don't use node.js.
HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Persoană care sare în Three.js</title>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
  </style>
</head>
```

```
<body>
  <script src="three.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
  <script type="module">


import * as THREE from "./three.js";
import {GLTFLoader} from "./GLTFLoader.js";

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
    .01,
    1000
);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


var loader = new GLTFLoader();  
var obj;
loader.load("scene.gltf", function(gltf){
    obj = gltf.scene
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
});

scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF);
var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0x000000,2);
scene.add(light);
camera.position.set(0,0,100);
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
animate();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but i keep getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Is your `three.js` a module? Looks like it as you use it as one, which means it might be importing other modules with `from "three/..."`, which is not native JS but needs to be compiled. You also import them twice (don't do that to avoid any unintended issues) (once as a script, once as an import), remove the `script` files to make your code less noisy and easier to debug. Also, pretty sure VSCode is going to be using node internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should include these two scripts in your HTML file:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@<version>/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@<version>/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
```

More information here:
https://threejs.org/docs/manual/en/introduction/Installation.html

(in Option 2)